# An undirect and connected graph $G=(V,E)$ can be turned into a direct strongly connected graph $G_D$ if and only if graph $G$ does not have bridges

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> An undirected and connected graph $G=(V,E)$ can be turned into a directed strongly connected graph $G_D$ if and only if graph $G$ does not have bridges.

Where the definition of bridge is:

> A bridge edge in a graph is an edge that removing it will turn the graph to be unconnected.

I proved one way:

> Let $G=\left(V,E\right)$ be an undirected and connected graph $G=(V,E)$ that can be turned into a directed strongly connected graph $G_{D}=\left(V,E_{D}\right)$. We will prove that $G$ does not have bridges. Lets there be an edge $e=\{u,v\}\in E$. Lets assume by contradiction that removing $e$ from $G$ will make $G$ to be unconnected. Lets remove $e$ so we get $G_{e}=\left(V,E\backslash\{e\}\right)$. Let there be $s,t\in V$.
>
> - If there is a path in $G$ between $s$ and $t$ that does not go through $e$ then it exists in $G_e$. This means that $G_e$ is connected.
> - If there are no paths that in $G$ between $s$ and $t$ that does not go through $e$ then all of the paths from $s$ to $t$ are going though $e$. Lets look at $G_{D}$ and assume that $e$ turns into $e'=(u,v)\in E$. Since $G_{D}$ is a strongly connected graph, this means that there is a path $P$ between $v$ and $u$. Since $e'$ goes from $u$ to $v$, this means that it's not part of the path $P$. This means that path $P$ with the edge $(u,v)$ close a cycle. This means that this cycle exists in the undirected graph $G$. Removing an edge from a cycle does not make it undirected. This means that removing $e$ from $G$ does not make in unconnected.
>
> In any case, removing edge from $G$ does not make it undirected. This means that $G$ does not have bridge edges.

I'm struggling to prove the other way around. Is it possible to help me with the other way?